# Can we find and invite all supporters from the previously failed Area51 attempts to build this site?

Tags: discussion, support

Robert Cartaino contacted the supporters of a failed Mathematica.SE proposal when a subsequent proposal became successful:

> [Since the Mathematica proposal is relaunching from the support of a
>   prior proposal, I will contact the remaining users to let them know
>   about the new proposal.](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3780/190792)

One of the benefits of entering Public Beta is that we now appear on Google searches. I searched "Materials Modeling Stack Exchange" to see what it would look like, and to my surprise I saw that the European Materials Modeling Council actually [tried in 2018 to make an SE site through Area51](https://nccr-marvel.ch/news/communication/2018-02-launch-of-emmc-csa-open-forum). That link shows that they had 20 followers in the first 5 days, and probably many more afterwards, since about 1 month later they [advertised on Twitter](https://twitter.com/EMMC_ASBL/status/968490054707548162) and it was re-tweeted several times. It appears that after a bit more than another month, they had 143 followers (more than us!):

[image]

While looking for that archive, I also found the following that would be of interest to us:

[image]
This site not only had questions about Rosetta, but related to Gaussian too, and they had questions about **docking**, which we already have on our site.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I also found the following in Area51 Discussion Zone (unfortunately I was not able to find them  on the waybackmachine but at least one of them I know is there):

- [Computational Quantum Chemistry](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20130/why-a-new-community-about-computational-quantum-chemistry)
- [Mechanical Engineering Design and Manufacturing](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/118650/mechanical-engineering-design-and-manufacturing)
- [Mechanical Engineering](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44908)

So I wonder if we could have the supporters of at least some of these old proposals informed that we had a site enter Private Beta? "Software for Materials Modeling" is basically our [software](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) tag, which with a few dozen questions is [our second most popular tag so far](https://materials.stackexchange.com/tags).